Showing that $ f(x) = 0 $ if the triple integral $\frac{f(x)}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)} $ converges
I'm told the following integral converges, and I'm asked to prove that $ f = 0 $, when it's a continuous function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)}\,dx\,dy\,dz.$
My attempt: Suppose that $ f(x_0) = M > 0$. Then there's a small enough interval such that $ f(x) > M/2, \forall x \in(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta).$
Then at that interval, $\int_{x_0 - \delta}^{x_0 + \delta}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)}\, dx\,dy\,dz > \int_{x_0 - \delta}^{x_0 +\delta}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{M/2}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)}\,dx\,dy\,dz$.
If I can show that the double integral that corresponds to $y, z$ diverges, so does our original integral, and that is a contradiction - so $f = 0$ for all $x$.
I want to change to spherical coordinates, $x = r \cos a \cos b, y = r \cos a \cos b$, $z = r \sin a$. Then we have a triple integral, and one of those integrals is of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{r^2}{1+ r^2} dr $, and since its limit at $\infty$ is 1, our triple integral in this interval diverges - but we know that it must converge, so we reach a contradiction.
Is this attempt okay? What is not correct and needs refinement?

Is f continuous?

Yes. I updated it, thank you

I'm not sure that will work since the range of the $a$ and $b$ variables will shrink as you go outwards, so that the integrals in those variables might go to zero. It might be better to use that ${\displaystyle \frac{1}{1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \geq \frac{1}{N + y^2 + z^2}}$ for some large $N$ when $x$ is near $x_0$. Then you can just do polar coordinates in $y$ and $z$ to show that the integral in $y$ and $z$ is either $\infty$ or $-\infty$, and therefore the three-dimensional integral will not converge.

Not true. Consider $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$.

I think the OP substantially changed the question after you posted

This counter example still holds probably with a version in $\mathbb{R}^3 $given by $\frac{x}{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}$. I think that has an integral of 0 as well for similar reasons. Clearly $f \ne 0$

In layman's terms, for  convergence you need that the limit of the integrals over rectangular boxes converges to the same $L$, regardless of how the boxes grow to ${\mathbb R}^3$.

To add a bit to the comment above: You seem to have interpreted the triple integral as to "first integrate $x$ over $\mathbb{R}$, then $y$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and then $z$ over $\mathbb{R}$" and you conclude it converges to $0$ since the first integral is the zero function. However with the usual definition of a triple integral ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Mathematical_definition ) this integral will nevertheless be divergent.

@Zarrax, that may be the case. However, just like 1D integrals, if we define $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dxdy=\lim_{(a,b,c,d)\to(-\infty,\infty,-\infty,\infty)}\int_{a}^b\int_{c}^df(x,y)dxdy$, it is ambiguous which of $a,b,c,d$ bumps to $\pm\infty$ "sooner than others". It is generally impossible to exchange integral in a multiple integral. This is a very well-known concept, e.g. for convergence and absolute convergence of series, where re-ordering of terms is allowed for a convergent series only if it is absolutely convergent.

@SidharthGhoshal, I presume my example still serves as a counter one.

@Winther, the definition is based on bounded domains. To extend it to unbounded domains for improper integrals, you need to tend the bounds to $\pm\infty$. I have provided a more detailed response in my second to last comment.

@Zarrax OPs set up might be true in that case. I’m not sure if such a syntax exists but it’s like the difference between an “absolutely convergent” integral vs a “conditionally convergent” integral of which Mostafa has used the latter in his counter example

@MostafaAyaz Could you clarify what is exactly the argument you are making? Your comment seem to me to provide arguments in favor of the objection Zarrax pointed out. The fact that it can be ambiguous is exactly why we introduce the notion of a "convergent integral" in the first place and require that the limit to be the same no matter how the limit is taken. When its convergent then its not ambiguous anymore.

@SidharthGhoshal The integral is not convergent, conditionally or absolutely, because even for conditional convergence you need the limit to exist and be the same over all possible sequences of boxes $[-K_1, K_2] \times [-L_1, L_2] \times [-M_1, M_2]$ where $K_1,K_2, L_1, L_2, M_1,$ and $M_2$ go to infinity.

I don’t have a word for it. But there’s some concept weaker than conditional convergence but not totally divergent here, let’s call it balanced convergent. And mostafa’s integral balance converges to 0. But OP wants regular convergence and not balance convergence so hence Mostafa’s example no longer applies. I was hasty in assuming this balance convergence is the same as regular convergence .

If you consider cubes centered at 0 with equal side lengths (the most “natural” way to approximate it) it’s easy to see the 0 integral result.

@MostafaAyaz If you use intervals $[−A, A^2]×[−A,A]×[−A,A]$ the integrals go to infinity as $A$ goes to infinity. Thus your example doesn't work.

@Zarrax, you are correct. The main point is the definition of an improper multiple integral based on proper ones, for which there are infinitely many such defs. I took Cauchy's principal value for the case. If the question demands the same question with the extra condition that the integral vanishes, no matter how its bounds tend to $\pm\infty$ or no matter what is the order of integration, then the proposition is true.

@MostafaAyaz There is a notion of Cauchy principal value in three dimensions but that too doesn't apply to your example. It concerns when an integrand blows up at a single point, which is a quite different scenario.

@Zarrax, pardon my doubt, but I think integrals like $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xdx\equiv\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^axdx$ are also alternative applications of CPV (Cauchy's Principal Value).
